Getting Embeddings from the base model in torchensemble
I've been learning Torchensemble, and I wanted to know how you can extract the embeddings before the final classification layer.
Here is my ensemble model:
VotingClassifier(
 (base_estimator_): CCT(
  (tokenizer): Tokenizer(
   (conv_layers): Sequential(
    (0): Sequential(
     (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
     (1): ReLU()
     (2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
    (1): Sequential(
     (0): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
     (1): ReLU()
     (2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
   )
   (flattener): Flatten(start_dim=2, end_dim=3)
  )
  (classifier): TransformerClassifier(
   (attention_pool): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=1, bias=True)
   (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
   (blocks): ModuleList(
    (0): TransformerEncoderLayer(
     (pre_norm): LayerNorm((256,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
     (self_attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=768, bias=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=256, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
     )
     (linear1): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=512, bias=True)
     (dropout1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
     (norm1): LayerNorm((256,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
     (linear2): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=256, bias=True)
     (dropout2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
     (drop_path): Identity()
    )
    (1-6): 6 x TransformerEncoderLayer(
     (pre_norm): LayerNorm((256,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
     (self_attn): Attention(
      (qkv): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=768, bias=False)
      (attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=256, bias=True)
      (proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
     )
     (linear1): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=512, bias=True)
     (dropout1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
     (norm1): LayerNorm((256,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
     (linear2): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=256, bias=True)
     (dropout2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
     (drop_path): DropPath()
    )
   )
   (norm): LayerNorm((256,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
   (fc): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=5013, bias=True)
  )
 )
 (estimators_): ModuleList()
 (_criterion): CrossEntropyLoss()
)

You see, there is a fully connected layer (fc) in the last of the base model. I want to delete it or replace it with Identity. How to do it? It seems removing the layer in the base estimator does not do anything.
The forward method of the base model (CCT) looks like this:

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.tokenizer(x)
        return self.classifier(x)


It depends on the tokenizer and the classifier

class Tokenizer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 kernel_size, stride, padding,
                 pooling_kernel_size=3, pooling_stride=2, pooling_padding=1,
                 n_conv_layers=1,
                 n_input_channels=3,
                 n_output_channels=64,
                 in_planes=64,
                 activation=None,
                 max_pool=True,
                 conv_bias=False):
        super(Tokenizer, self).__init__()

        n_filter_list = [n_input_channels] + \
                        [in_planes for _ in range(n_conv_layers - 1)] + \
                        [n_output_channels]

        self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential(
            *[nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(n_filter_list[i], n_filter_list[i + 1],
                          kernel_size=(kernel_size, kernel_size),
                          stride=(stride, stride),
                          padding=(padding, padding), bias=conv_bias),
                nn.Identity() if activation is None else activation(),
                nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=pooling_kernel_size,
                             stride=pooling_stride,
                             padding=pooling_padding) if max_pool else nn.Identity()
            )
                for i in range(n_conv_layers)
            ])

        self.flattener = nn.Flatten(2, 3)
        self.apply(self.init_weight)

    def sequence_length(self, n_channels=3, height=224, width=224):
        return self.forward(torch.zeros((1, n_channels, height, width))).shape[1]

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.flattener(self.conv_layers(x)).transpose(-2, -1)

    @staticmethod
    def init_weight(m):
        if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
            nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight)

class TransformerClassifier(Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 seq_pool=True,
                 embedding_dim=768,
                 num_layers=12,
                 num_heads=12,
                 mlp_ratio=4.0,
                 num_classes=1000,
                 dropout=0.1,
                 attention_dropout=0.1,
                 stochastic_depth=0.1,
                 positional_embedding='learnable',
                 sequence_length=None):
        super().__init__()
        positional_embedding = positional_embedding if \
            positional_embedding in ['sine', 'learnable', 'none'] else 'sine'
        dim_feedforward = int(embedding_dim * mlp_ratio)
        self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.seq_pool = seq_pool
        self.num_tokens = 0

        assert sequence_length is not None or positional_embedding == 'none', \
            f"Positional embedding is set to {positional_embedding} and" \
            f" the sequence length was not specified."

        if not seq_pool:
            sequence_length += 1
            self.class_emb = Parameter(torch.zeros(1, 1, self.embedding_dim),
                                       requires_grad=True)
            self.num_tokens = 1
        else:
            self.attention_pool = Linear(self.embedding_dim, 1)

        if positional_embedding != 'none':
            if positional_embedding == 'learnable':
                self.positional_emb = Parameter(torch.zeros(1, sequence_length, embedding_dim),
                                                requires_grad=True)
                init.trunc_normal_(self.positional_emb, std=0.2)
            else:
                self.positional_emb = Parameter(self.sinusoidal_embedding(sequence_length, embedding_dim),
                                                requires_grad=False)
        else:
            self.positional_emb = None

        self.dropout = Dropout(p=dropout)
        dpr = [x.item() for x in torch.linspace(0, stochastic_depth, num_layers)]
        self.blocks = ModuleList([
            TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=embedding_dim, nhead=num_heads,
                                    dim_feedforward=dim_feedforward, dropout=dropout,
                                    attention_dropout=attention_dropout, drop_path_rate=dpr[i])
            for i in range(num_layers)])
        self.norm = LayerNorm(embedding_dim)

        self.fc = Linear(embedding_dim, num_classes)
        self.apply(self.init_weight)

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.positional_emb is None and x.size(1) < self.sequence_length:
            x = F.pad(x, (0, 0, 0, self.n_channels - x.size(1)), mode='constant', value=0)

        if not self.seq_pool:
            cls_token = self.class_emb.expand(x.shape[0], -1, -1)
            x = torch.cat((cls_token, x), dim=1)

        if self.positional_emb is not None:
            x += self.positional_emb

        x = self.dropout(x)

        for blk in self.blocks:
            x = blk(x)
        x = self.norm(x)

        if self.seq_pool:
            x = torch.matmul(F.softmax(self.attention_pool(x), dim=1).transpose(-1, -2), x).squeeze(-2)
        else:
            x = x[:, 0]

        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

    @staticmethod
    def init_weight(m):
        if isinstance(m, Linear):
            init.trunc_normal_(m.weight, std=.02)
            if isinstance(m, Linear) and m.bias is not None:
                init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
        elif isinstance(m, LayerNorm):
            init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
            init.constant_(m.weight, 1.0)

    @staticmethod
    def sinusoidal_embedding(n_channels, dim):
        pe = torch.FloatTensor([[p / (10000 ** (2 * (i // 2) / dim)) for i in range(dim)]
                                for p in range(n_channels)])
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(pe[:, 0::2])
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(pe[:, 1::2])
        return pe.unsqueeze(0)

And the forward method of torchensemble looks like this:
    def forward(self, *x):

        outputs = [
            F.softmax(op.unsqueeze_tensor(estimator(*x)), dim=1)
            for estimator in self.estimators_
        ]

        if self.voting_strategy == "soft":
            proba = op.average(outputs)
        else:
            proba = op.majority_vote(outputs)

        return proba

It extends a base class
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def forward(self, *x):
        """
        Implementation on the data forwarding in the ensemble. Notice
        that the input ``x`` should be a data batch instead of a standalone
        data loader that contains many data batches.
        """



the answer depends on what the forward method of the model looks like
